# Where do I find the namespace of an app [Android]

Tags: android, namespaces

I need to find the **namespace** of the app, so I can fill in the value for the assetlinks.json file.

```
https://www.domain1.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.mycompany.app1",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Tim, I was looking for this too because the Google docs never explained the namespace field in the json. As it turns out, you leave the value as `android_app`, this tells consumers these settings are specifically for an android_app. It is not to specify the specific namespace of your app or project (like I also assumed)

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app

> **Target:** Using the namespace value of android_app determines the android app that receives the URLs. Configure it using its package name and the SHA-256 fingerprint of the certificate you used to sign your app before deploying it to the Play Store. See Signing Your Applications to learn more about deployment and your signing certificate.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the @johnw182 answer, just want to add, that wrong name leads to unpredictable errors and I spent a lot of time to find them.
But it is possible to validate the `assetlinks.json` file

Just change YOUR_WEB_SITE_ADDRESS to web-site with `assetlinks.json` file.

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://YOUR_WEB_SITE_ADDRESS&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

Comment: thanks! I didn't knew about this important tool

Comment: This tool is a life saver !! Thanks a lot 

In my case , the redirection didn't work because i was using the test servers & got a Invalid-SSL error